# php and regex: search for word in string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How can i found word in string using regex or not in this string

**String is Mysql Query**

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  desc,
  (SELECT id as lid FROM comments WHERE lid = id order by id desc limit 1) as lid_com
 FROM posts limit 3
```

here i want to search for **limit** in the last of string

string may be

```
  limit 3
  limit 3, 3
  limit 3 , 3
  limit 3 ,3
```

3 here may be any number

i tried this regex but i'm beginner

> "/ limit [0-9]{0,9}+\,[0-9]{0,9} /i$"

how can i do this

Thank you

Comment: may be query is not vaild mysql query but i added it with subquery wth limit word  , heres query contain 2 words of limit ^-^

Comment: Would this question : "How to find the first word of a string" fit better to what you are looking for ?

Comment: @FailedDev yes i want to find it in the main query not in the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'SELECT
  id,
  name,
  desc,
  (SELECT id as lid FROM comments WHERE lid = id order by id desc limit 1) as lid_com
 FROM posts limit 3 ,3';

echo preg_match('/(limit)\s\d(((\,\s)|(\s\,\s)|(\s\,))\d)?$/i', $string, $matches);  //1
print_r($matches); //$matches['0'] == 'limit 3 ,3'
```

Comment: Thank you @lng  ,  your regex work fine , but not with this `limit 3,3`

Comment: Now its work fine after regex become `/(limit)\s\d(((\,\s)|(\s\,\s)|(\s\,))\d)?$/i` , but as @kirilloid said  limit is not always last statment  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html , this will need some more work :)

Comment: Just take out the `$` so the regex will match anywhere in the string, not just the end :)

Comment: This Will affect sub query if found , i want the main query

Answer (score 1):

```
"/limit[\s]+[\d]+[\s]*,[\s]*[\d]+$/i"
```

This searches case insesitive for:

- "limit"
- one or more whitespaces
- one or more digits
- zero or more whitespaces
- a comma
- zero or more whitespaces
- one or more digits
- at the end of the string

Comment: maybe add ' posts ' before 'limit' to only get the second occurrence

Comment: not work ( without comment on your answer ) , and i will not control the query :(

Answer (score 1):

Do not remember, whether `LIMIT` is always a last SQL statement, so I'd use

```
/limit\s+(\d+)(?:\s*,\s*(\d+))?(?=[^\n]+\Z)/mi
```

Comment: Thank you for answer . but this regex work with the subquery too ??   i want to check it in the main query only not sub queries

Comment: It matches only those `limit` statement, which is located on the last line. Parsing arbitrary SQL code with regexes isn't good idea.

Comment: Find some SQL code parser and integrate it =) But actually your underlying problem may be solved w/o replacing at all, just try to solve it from another side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column
  REGEXP '(^limit[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+$)|(^limit[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*$)';
```

The first part find strings like 'limit 3,3' -

```
^limit[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+$
```

The second one finds strings like 'limit 3' -

```
^limit[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*$
```